# GAE Python - PyCrypto - No module named winrandom

Tags: python, windows, google-app-engine, pycrypto

I am trying to get PyCrypto up and running on my App Engine (Python) Development Server. I installed PyCrypto using a [Voidspace](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/modules.shtml#pycrypto) binary file (pycrypto-2.0.1.win-amd64-py2.6.exe).

I am running Windows 7 64-bit. From what I found this binary from Voidspace does not install winrandom correctly because winrandom does not have a 64-bit binary. I have tried compiling a 64-bit version using VS 2008, but this is way outside of my knowledge and I don't know if I am doing it right. I followed the [following](http://blog.victorjabur.com/2011/06/05/compiling-python-2-7-modules-on-windows-32-and-64-using-msvc-2008-express/) directions for PyCrypto but instead tried to compile the winrandom source.

Comment: I have had only difficulty and no successes with C Extensions in windows 64bit python builds.  Consider trying your luck with the 32 bit python for windows.

Comment: I'd second TokenMacGuy. I do use both Windows and OSX development environments and I realized that going 32 bit (even on a 64 bit OS) saves me some trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Since pycrypto is part of the [third-party libraries for Google App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27), it should not be necessary to manually install pycrypto to use it in your project. Instead, you need to add the library to your app.yaml:

```
libraries:
- name: pycrypto
  version: "2.6"
```

Comment: This is not correct, pycrypto is one of the libs that are not bundled with the dev server.